# call javascript function from code behind C# web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

i have a javascript function say 'onclientclicking'.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnClientClicking(button, args) {
            window.location = button.get_navigateUrl();
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
    </script>
```

I want to execute this function from code behind.  What i am trying to do is  based on certain conditions, i need to set the event to telerik button

```
rad_btn_text.Attributes["OnClientClicking"] = javascript function;
```

how can it be possible?

regards,

Sivajith S

Comment: paste ur html(design) code..

Comment: You can't call a javascript function from code behind. You can just associate method (javascript-function) with control. Or if you want to call it it should be a part of your response stream. And when browser will start rendering the form it will execute that function once it reach there.

Comment: Could you plese mark as answered or provide feedback?

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
rad_btn_text.OnClientClicking = "OnClientClicking";
```

It's working on my machine™

Answer (score 0):

You can't "call" client side javascript from the server. That said, you can wire up client side events and emit client side code.

I don't use telrik controls but the asp.net property is onclientclick. Not sure if that is the same on a telerik control and the client side event is onclick.

Comment: @sivajith used a common approach in the telerik RadControls and the event name and function it's ok. He just need to set the javascript function server side.

Answer (score 0):

To call the javascript function from server side:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "OnClientClicking", "OnClientClicking();", True);
```

**References**

- [help on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)
- [OnClientclicking in telerik](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-onclientclicking.html)

Comment: this button is user control

Comment: @somnath-kharat consider upgrading your answer to the [new method ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
rad_btn_text.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnClientClicking()")
```

Hopefully this works for you

Answer (score -1):

try this. when user click on button the function of "OnClientClicking" will be executed :

```
rad_btn_text.Attributes["onclick"] = "OnClientClicking()";
```

Comment: This solution it's not good with telerik controls and wont fit the arguments of the question's function.